# when i open a pdf in adobe acrobat pro Dc the text is getting messed up for pdf creation i used itext5.5.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, itext, pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat

For our application we have used itext5.5.12 for pdf creation, ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.2

After downloading the pdf to our local machine from application  and open the pdf in Adobe Acrobat DC Pro the text is getting messed up see below pdf

[image: open the picture]

Please suggest me how to fix this problem

here is my code

```
FileStream = Rjb::import('java.io.FileOutputStream')
LicenseKey = Rjb::import('com.itextpdf.license.LicenseKey')
PdfReader = Rjb::import('com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader')
Document = Rjb::import('com.itextpdf.text.Document')
PdfCopy = Rjb::import('com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy')

def initialize(output_filename, pdf_files)
  itext_key = File.join(Rails.root, '/lib/jars/itextkey.xml')
  LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(itext_key)
  @output_filename = output_filename
  @pdf_files = pdf_files
end

def bind
  doc =Document.new
  pdf_copy = PdfCopy.new(doc, FileStream.new(@output_filename))
  doc.open
  @pdf_files.each do |pdf|
    reader = PdfReader.new(pdf)
    pages = reader.getNumberOfPages()
    (1..pages).each do |p|
      pdf_copy.addPage(pdf_copy.getImportedPage(reader, p))
    end
    reader.close
  end
  doc.close
end
```

Comment: Show us your code. Which fonts did you use? Did you embed them? Also: a screenshot doesn't help; share the full PDF file. Upload it to Dropbox, and share the link.

Comment: As Bruno indicates, your question does nor contain any information that can be used to help you with the errors in your code. Thus, please supply the required information.

Comment: Please also share the actual sample pdf.

Comment: Could you please check the above code and let me know where i am wrong.@BrunoLowagie

Comment: If possible you had better share the file using some file sharing service allowing public file shares (e.g. public googledrive or dropbox shares) so others can inspect the file, too. If that is not possible, you find an email address in my stack overflow profile.

Comment: @kishoresagar I received your mail and analyzed the PDFs therein. Cf. my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code

First of all, I ported your code to Java, ran it for the files you provided (cf. [Merging.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/Merging.java#L52)), but the result file was undamaged. Thus, the code you provided most likely is not the issue.

#### Post processors

Then I analyzed your PDF file and saw that your code was not the final editor of it:

- The Producer line says:

  > iText® 5.5.12 ©2000-2017 iText Group NV (yash; Trial version ka2lzaG9yZS5yYWNoYWtvbmRhQHlhc2guY29t); modified using iText® 7.0.1 ©2000-2016 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)

  Thus, another routine using iText 7.0.1 has post-processed the merged PDF.
- The PDF is linearized.

  As far as I know neither iText 5.x nor iText 7.0.x can create linearized files.

  Thus, yet another transformation by an unknown PDF processor took place.

So either the code using iText 7 or the unknown linearizing post processor might have introduced the issue.

#### The issue itself

I compared the originals you provided and your result. The difference:

The pages in "3 SLC Dec.pdf" reference a font resource for **Arial-BoldMT** which is not embedded. Thus, if the computer on which the PDF is displayed has that font, the PDF is properly displayed.

The matching pages in your result "39bdd9b1ba6501b44d401ee1b157ddb5631fcf36.pdf", though, reference a font resource for **Arial-BoldMT** which suddenly does have an embedded font file. But this font file is incomplete, i.e. merely a subset of **Arial-BoldMT**!

If there is an embedded font file, this embedded font file is used for displaying the text drawn in this font, not a font on the local computer anymore. As this embedded font file here is incomplete, numerous characters don't appear anymore.

Looking further it turns out that this subset font file is from your input "5 Sched of INS.pdf". Indeed, the only page in this PDF has a font resource for  **Arial-BoldMT** with a font file which only contains the characters needed for that page.

So either the code using iText 7 or the unknown linearizing post processor seems to have assumed that the **Arial-BoldMT** font file from "5 Sched of INS.pdf" is complete, and has added it to **Arial-BoldMT** font resources on other pages.

#### Was this an error?

This appears to have been a valid optimization step by the post processor which did this and not an error, because strictly speaking the **Arial-BoldMT** font resource in "5 Sched of INS.pdf" is broken; the PDF specification requires:

> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font — the value of the font’s BaseFont entry and the font descriptor’s FontName entry — shall begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+). The tag shall consist of exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary, but different subsets in the same PDF file shall have different tags.

As the **Arial-BoldMT** font resource in "5 Sched of INS.pdf" does not have this prefix, any font file embedded in it must be complete. But the embedded font file is not.

**Thus, which post processor ever actually did add the font file to the other font resources was allowed to do so, the "5 Sched of INS.pdf" file is the culprit and should be repaired before usage.**

Comment: Thanks for your information mkl. you are saying that need to repair  "5 Sched of INS.pdf" means it should be "Arial-BoldMT(embedded subset) " font.

Comment: "5 Sched of INS.pdf" needs to be repaired. Either the embedded font file shall be replaced by the complete font file or, if it remains a subset, its **BaseFont** and **FontName** properties shall be as described in my quote from the specification, or it should not be embedded at all. Thus, it may say "Arial-BoldMT(embedded)" or "Arial-BoldMT(embedded subset)" or "Arial-BoldMT", *as long as its built correctly*.

Comment: Can we embedded Arial-BoldMT fonts programmatically and also i need to include the fonts which i have been using in pdf.

Comment: *"Can we embedded Arial-BoldMT fonts programmatically"* - You mean into the existing files? For that you might be interested in studying the example [EmbedFontPostFacto.java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#607-embedfontpostfacto.java) from [iText in Action - Second Edition](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books#iia2nd).